# How i can Store top 5 Scores With names in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

i need your help,i Am stuck in a simple problem,i done a lot of googling but did not get solution.

I want to store Top 5 scores and with names, i done score by NSUserDefaults but don't know how to store it with names.Please help me.I really need your help.
THANKS...

Answer (score 1):

you can save into user defaults as

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary* dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"jonny",@"name",@"100",@"score", nil];
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict, nil];
[defaults setObject:arr forKey:@"list"];
[defaults synchronize];
[dict release];
[arr release];
```

and read the values as

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* arr = [defaults objectForKey:@"list"];
NSLog(@"%@",[arr objectAtIndex:0]);
```

this works fine for you, it will be a array of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks alot it looks great but only one confusion that is how i can get only top 5 rather than complete list

Comment: totally how many it may be..? after getting the array u can get any number of data right

Comment: Add your new score to the dictionary then use a for-loop to check for the lowest and remove it if there are more than 5

Comment: @Dancreek but in this way how can i remove or add name for that score holder user

Comment: You need to read up on how to use NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary. The documentation is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you familiarize yourself with basic Objective-C collection classes. You can use an NSDictionary to store objects, and those objects can be other objects. You can use this dictionary in combination with NSUserDefaults to store only what you want to store, after having some logic in your app that analyzes your collection class.

Pick up a good book on Objective-C and study sets, arrays and dictionaries.